# How to hide Facebook applications developers?

Tags: facebook

How can I hide Facebook applications developers from the application page?

When clicking on the edit information in the page, it takes me to the application settings. I can remove developers, but I can't manage to find where I can hide them!

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable "Sandbox Mode". This way, it will only be visible by developers. Remember it can show an 4oh4's page if you are not logged as a developer.

Edit: Okay, I didn't read your post correctly, you want to hide whom are the developers of an application. I believe this information is not available, is this a "Canvas Page" or a "Fan Page"?

Comment: 10x for your reply, but I want the app live not in sandbox mode, I want it to be visible an accessible, but i don't want people to know that I am the developer

Comment: Canvas, it's the app Profile page(the app is a game hosted on my server)

Answer (score 0):

It used to be that setting a company name (really just a text string) in the application information section would show that company name instead of a list of developers. Unfortunately I can't find this "company" field anymore in the new apps editor (https://developers.facebook.com/apps/), but you may be able to find it if you still are using the old (http://www.facebook.com/developers/).

Answer (score 0):

Please visit this thread: http://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/?view=permalink&id=244146462295542

It is a bug, Facebook is aware of it.